# Copy a file from local filesystem to Docker Container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile

```
FROM  myregistry.de/public/12/s11

LABEL maintainer="Me"    

COPY ./somefile.txt /opt


CMD /bin/sh
```

the file I want to copy to Docker Container is in the same folder as the Dockerfile

But when I do `docker build -t 'name:tag4' .`
I get the error message :

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat somefile.txt: **file does not exist**
```

So why is this simple copy not working ?

Comment: try mounting that file as a volume

Comment: Are you sure that you have `somefile.txt` in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`? And that `somefile .txt` is not in the `.dockerignore`?

Comment: Can you include in your question the output of `ls -A` or `tree -a` in the directory that contains your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Please check that it's really `somefile.txt`, not `someFile.txt` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Please check what you get in build context directory by creating another Dockerfile with the following content:

```
FROM  myregistry.de/public/12/s11
RUN mkdir /tmp/build
COPY . /tmp/build
CMD /bin/sh
```

Then build and run the container and check `/tmp/build` folder contents.

Comment: building the image worked but how can I run the image ? I did "docker run name:tag4" but in the folder where the Dockerfile lies I cannot see the /tmp/build Folder .

Comment: I also included an "RUN echo "Hello World" but I cannot see it in the console output. I am new to Docker. Do I have to go into the container to see it ??

Comment: You can run it with `docker run name:tag4 ls /tmp/build` to get the listing from inside the container. Or even run it in interactive mode with `docker run -it name:tag4` and you will get into the shell running in the container, where you can run command `ls /tmp/build/` and do other troubleshooting steps.

Comment: The difference between `RUN` and `CMD` commands is that `RUN` is executed when you build the image, and `CMD` - when you run the comtainer. You should be able to see the output from `RUN` command on a build stage if you run `docker build --progress plain -t name:tag4 .`

Comment: Ok. Nice. When I go inside the container I see "sh-4.4"  at the beginning of the shell. What is it ?

Comment: I put 
CMD echo 'Hello World!'
in the Dockerfile but I never see the output.
What can I do to see the echo?? By the way I am using docker on a Wsl .

Comment: Another fact I don't understand. If I want to copy a specific file "COPY ./myfile.tgz /opt" and if this file lies in a folder with many other files and folders . Then if I don't have a dockerignore file it takes ages or it never stops . Hm

Comment: `sh-4.4` is just the command prompt. Probably telling you that you are running `sh` version 4.4. You can run various commands in this shell. Start with `ls /tmp/build` (`ls` is the same as `dir` in WIndows command propt) to see which files were copied from build context directory when building the image. And check if you have `somefile.txt` there (it should have exactly this name, since Linux file system is case sensitive, so `Somefile.txt` would not be copied by your `COPY ./somefile.txt /opt` command)

Comment: To see your 'Hello World!' output you need to build the image and run the container based on this image. `docker build -t hello .` and then `docker run --rm hello` (--rm tells docker to delete the container instance after you run it to free the disk space)

Comment: When you build the image Docker is first copying everything you have in the build context folder (current folder if you specify `.` in the end of `docker build -t name:tag4 .`) to the build environment. So if you have many files, then all of them will be copied there. And COPY commands will copy from that directory inside build environment, not from your local. You can either configure `.dockerignore` file or move `Dockerfile` and the files required for building the image into a separate folder.

Comment: If you want to understand how Docker works and how to work with it, I would recommend the following course on Udemy: https://www.udemy.com/course/docker-and-kubernetes-the-complete-guide/

Comment: You said "When you build the image Docker is first copying everything you have in the build context folder (current folder if you specify . in the end of docker build -t name:tag4 .) to the build environment."   

So why is Docker copying all in the folder ?? That explains why I had to wait ages because the file lives in a folder where there is lots of other stuff. I just need Docker to copy 1 or 2 files . All the other crap I don't need . I don't understand why Docker wants to copy files and subfolders I do not specifiy in the Dockerfile. Why is Docker doing this ???

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/understanding-the-docker-build-context-why-you-should-use-dockerignore/

Comment: You can see the size of the build context in the `docker build` output, e.g. `Sending build context to Docker daemon  372.5MB`. It's needed because image is built by docker daemon which doesn't have access to your source directory.

Comment: OK. So what I understand : The docker client would copy the whole content of the folder where the Dockerfile is to the Docker daemon . But when you have a dockerignore file the docker client will analyse it and copy just the files mentioned there. But it's just how Docker works. Basically the Docker Client could just analyse the Dockerfile and see which copy sources are mentioned there :) . But by the way is the Docker client looking into the Dockerfile or is only the Docker daemon analysing it  ?

Comment: After this message "Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.739MB"  only the Docker Daemon is doing work ??? But how can all the other steps be displayed at my console if Docker Daemon is for example a remote daemon . Hm..

Comment: See [Daemon socket option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option) for details how client talks to daemon. As for the responsibilities of the client, I believe there is a good reason why it's done this way. We just need to use `.dockerignore`.